# R-Shiny two way communication

Tags: r, shiny

We have separate process which provides data to our R-Shiny application. I know I can provide data to R-Shiny via file or database and observe the data source via `reactivePoll`. This works fine and I understand it's sort of recommended way.

What I don't like on this approach is:

- It's hard to send to shiny various type of inputs (like *data* and *metadata*)
- I miss the shiny application feedback to the data providing process. I just write a file and hope that shiny app will pick it up and process and will be successful. Data sourcing process cannot be notified about failure for example (invalid data)

I would love to have some 2-ways protocol. For example send the data through a websocket (this would have to be different websocket than the one Shiny has with the UI obviously) or raw socket and be able to send response back.

Surely I can implement some file-based API where I store files under different names observing them with shiny and shiny then writes other files back and I would observe them with my application which provided the data. But this basically sucks :)

Any tips much appreciated!

**Edit:** it mas or may not be obvious from saying the Java and R applications are writing files for each other ... But the apps are running on the same host and I can live with this limitation

Comment: Been using Zeromq for another project, and I note there are R binding for it. Would suggest looking into that.

Comment: Very lightweight and fast, multiplatform too. People that use 0MQ say it is far superior to trying to use sockets.

Comment: 0mq looks good by probably way too biv for my purposes. I shoukd have mentioned that I am ok with having my data producing app on the same host as R. Such messaging system for distributed environments sounds like overkill for my use case. Any tips on how to get started with sockets in R?

Comment: Err "biv"?  I suppose you mean heavy? 0mq is very lightweight. My impression is that people are abandoning sockets for this kind of lightweight library. I have not done sockets in R, and don't think I would anymore because of 0mq. I have used it in Python and C.